# How to extract the "Automation creation status" and "Automation Required status" count from all the test cases of project from Test Rail

Tags: automation, testrail

How to extract the "Automation creation status" and "Automation Required status" count from all the test cases of project from Test Rail?

I dont see any option to extract just above data, Is it a limitation or can you please suggest on steps for it.